# How to enable custom context menu in Ag Grid Master and Detail row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In Ag Grid is there any way to enable different context menu for parent and child rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in getContextMenuItems function.

In the grid definition:

```
:get-context-menu-items="getContextMenuItems"
```

and in this function:

```
const function getContextMenuItems = (params) => {
  if (params.node.level === 0) {
    return [WhateverMenuForParent]
  } else {
    return [WhateverMenuForChild]
  }
}
```

You can also test: `ìf (params.node.group)`